# C#/.NET Date: From local to UTC

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I get date data from a user. That data is a date (e.g. 4/23/2011) and an hour (0 - 23), representing the time. This date/time that the user selects is a local time.

I need to convert this to a UTC DateTime. I have their GMTOffset for their location. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var utcDateTime = 
     new DateTimeOffset(userDateTime, TimeSpan.FromHours(userUtcOffset)).UtcDateTime;
```

Of course you can use `TimeSpan` differently if the GMT offset has minutes / fractions of an hour.

Answer (score 1):

You should work with the [`DateTimeOffset` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx), specifically, the [constructor that takes the `DateTime` and the `TimeSpan` that represents the offset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351980.aspx).

From there, conversions to/from UTC are a breeze, as the offset is embedded in the structure and not dependent on local system settings.

Note, even though not commonly adhered to, it is [recommended to work with `DateTimeOffset` most of the time, as opposed to `DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384267.aspx) (see the note under the section titled "The DateTimeOffset Structure").

Answer (score -1):

Just use the DateTime.ToUniversalTime in C#, will that do what you want?

Comment: This will only work if the processing is done on the same machine the input was done.

Comment: @-1: This does not do what he wants as it will convert the `DateTime` structure to UTC according to the *current system's* offset from UTC.  The need is to do the conversion using an *arbitrary* offset.

Comment: That is my understanding too.

Comment: @John Batdorf: No biggie, you can always change your answer.

Comment: @Mohamed Meligy: Your understanding is correct, it's just that the OP specified that they are getting the GMT offset from another location, so it can't be guaranteed that the offsets are the same.